# Вычисление размеров видео. Высота блока

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, блок

Смотрел видеоурок [Адаптивная верстка сайта с нуля для начинающих. Объяснение действий. HTML CSS. ЧАСТЬ №2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UUK4VDblXM&t=5844s) с 14:00-17:50. В нем вычисляются размеры видео (в блоке на сайте) в %. Размеры видео - 600*442. Ширина блока контейнера - 1046px (если я конечно правильно понял значение этого числа - 1046px). Есть следующий класс

```css
.whoweare__body {
  display: flex;
}

.whoweare__video {
  flex: 0 0 57%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 0px 42.25% 0px;
}

.whoweare__video iframe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.whoweare__content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="page__whoweare whoweare">
  <div class="whoweare__container _container">
    <div class="whoweare__header header-block">
      <h2 class="header-block__title">Who We Are</h2>
      <div class="header-block__sub-title">
        Problems trying to resolve the conflict between the two major realms <br> of Classical physics: Newtonian mechanics
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="whoweare__body">
      <div class="whoweare__video">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ef-47vI9PDs" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="whoweare__content">
        <div class="whoweare__top">
          <h2 class="whoweare__title">Most trusted in our field</h2>
          <div class="whoweare__text">Most calendars are designed for teams. Slate is designed for freelancers who want a simple way to plan their schedule.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="whoweare__items">
          <div class="whoweare__item item-whoweare">
            <div class="item-whoweare__icon">
              <img src="img/whoweare/icons/01.svg">
            </div>
            <div class="item-whoweare__body">
              <div class="item-whoweare__title">the quick fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
              <div class="item-whoweare__text">Things on a very small scale ...</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="whoweare__item item-whoweare">
            <div class="item-whoweare__icon">
              <img src="img/whoweare/icons/02.svg">
            </div>
            <div class="item-whoweare__body">
              <div class="item-whoweare__title">the quick fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
              <div class="item-whoweare__text">Things on a very small scale ...</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ширина видео в % вычисляется как `calc(600/1046*100%)` (`flex-basis: 57%`). А высота видео вычисляется как `calc(442/1046*100%)` (`padding-bottom: 42.25%`). Вот с высотой возникают 2 вопроса:

**1. Почему высота равна padding?**

**2. Почему высота видео 442px делится на ширину контейнера 1046px, а не на высоту сайта?**

Возможно я перепутал размеры объектов и расстояния между ними (если что поправьте меня, но скорее всего я не ошибся).

`1046px` взято с [1-ой части](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-irDQwt1l4&t=4348s) с 35:15. Если я ошибся, поправьте. Прилагаю макет сайта [Relvise](https://www.figma.com/file/aHTuIXsuQ7ehqEYynSFKid/Relvise-(1)?node-id=964%3A5456) - блок Who We Are (только в макете видео не с youtube было взято). Даже не знаю как эффективно загуглить (касательно моей проблемы).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. padding === height потому, что так свёрстано. iframe идёт с position absolute, поэтому высоту надо было задавать явно, можно было бы и через height но в примере почему-то через  padding-bottom
2. собственно высота считается в процентах от ширины из-за того, что процентный паддинг считается от ширины родителя (как оказалось) [документация MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-bottom)

> The size of the padding as a percentage, relative to the inline size (width in a horizontal language, defined by writing-mode) of the containing block. Must be nonnegative.